# Merge two NSArrays consisting of dictionaries, based on a parameter in dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, merge, nsmutablearray, filtering

I have a `NSMutableArray` and a `NSArray`. Both consist of elements that are `NSDictionarys` themselves.
A sample structure of both is as follows:

```
NSMutableArray
[
    {
        objectId = 4274;
        name = orange;
        price = 45;
        status = approved;
    },
        {
        objectId = 9035;
        name = apple;
        price = 56;
        status = approved;
    },
        {
        objectId = 7336;
        name = banana;
        price = 48;
        status = approved;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
]
```

and NSAraay is

```
NSArray
[
    {
        objectId = 4274;
        name = orange;
        price = 106;
        status = not_approved;
    },
        {
        objectId = 5503;
        name = apple;
        price = 56;
        status = approved;
    }
]
```

What I want is to merge these two arrays so that, if any element in `NSArray` has same `objectId` as any element in `NSMutableArray`, element in `NSArray` should overwrite on element in `NSMutableArray`.

So in this case final merged array should look like this

```
MergedArray
    [
        {
            objectId = 4274;
            name = orange;
            price = 106;
            status = not_approved;
        },
            {
            objectId = 9035;
            name = apple;
            price = 56;
            status = approved;
        },
            {
            objectId = 7336;
            name = banana;
            price = 48;
            status = approved;
        },
           {
            objectId = 5503;
            name = apple;
            price = 56;
            status = approved;
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
    ]
```

Only way to this I know is to iterate through both arrays and merge. Is there any better way? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Following dasblinkenlights suggestion, I did it following way

```
    -(NSMutableArray*)mergeTwoArray:(NSArray*)array1 :(NSArray*)array2
    {
//array1 will overwrite on array2
    NSSet* parentSet = [NSSet setWithArray:array2];

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        for (NSDictionary *item in parentSet) 
           [dict setObject: item forKey: [item objectForKey:@"objectId"]];


        NSLog(@"initial dictionary is %@",dict);
        for (NSDictionary *item in array1)            
            [dict setObject: item forKey: [item objectForKey:@"objectId"]];

        NSLog(@"final dictionary is %@ with all values %@", dict,[dict allValues]);

        return [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict allValues]];
    }
```

Comment: #9035 appears twice in your merged array.  Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `objectId` value can be used as a unique key, you could potentially create an `NSMutableDictionary` on the side, populate it with `NSDictionary` objects from the first array using `objectId` value as the key, go through the second array, do the overwrites, and finally harvest the values of the resultant `NSMutableDictionary` into your final output.

Note that this approach *might* be helpful only if your arrays are relatively long (1000+ items). If you deal with 10..100 items, I wouldn't bother, and code two nested loops as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I merged arrays the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend iterating through both arrays and merging, but first sort them.  Once sorted, you can merge two arrays in O(N) time.   For most purposes, this is about as fast as you can get, and it requires very little code.

If they are large enough that the sort is a bottleneck, you could get fancy using an `NSSet`: put the (elements of the) over-riding array in the set first, and then add the elements of the original array.  But you would have to implement an isEqual method for your elements.  In this case, it would mean that your elements would no longer be `NSDictionary`, but rather a class that inherits from `NSDictionary` but implements the isEqual method to compare the object ID fields.

Because `NSSet` gives amortized constant time access, this would be faster, if the arrays are large, since there is no sort phase.